# Deal with timezones in JS from UNIX timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I'm currently writing a small messaging app for global usage. I'm going to store the UTC timestamp of the message. I need to display the message to the user using AJAX, so i need to convert the UNIX timestamp to the users local time. I know how to get the timezone offset, but i'm afraid that it will be a little bit inaccurate and i need accuracy even in seconds (to display times like: 34 seconds ago). Which is the most accurate way to solve this?

Comment: My first tough was to compare the Date() and getUTC() values to calculate offset. Don't really know if that would be apporate.

Comment: var date = new Date(UTC+"000")

Answer (score 1):

Why not calculate the local date locally? Constructing a date with new Date(millisecondsSinceEpoch) locally and then calling toTimeString() (or whatever) should show you the local time:

```
new Date(milliseconds).toTimeString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date((new Date(1390312399000)).toUTCString());
```

Where the timestamp is the stored UTC timestamp.